# How to bind a form to database when the user has only INSERT privileges

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have a form bound to an Oracle database.

The form is intended to type data.

When the user has all the privileges on the table the form is connected to, everything works perfectly. But, when the user has only write access, the form can not be bound.

Here is the code I'm using to get the datatable to which all the form controls are bound to :

```
Private Function GetDataTable(ByVal TableName As String, ByVal SQL As String) As DataTable
    Dim Command As OracleCommand
    Dim DataSet As New DataSet
    Dim DataTable As DataTable
    Dim TempDataAdapter As OracleDataAdapter

    Command = New OracleCommand(SQL, OracleObject.Connection)
    TempDataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(Command)
    TempDataAdapter.FillSchema(DataSet, SchemaType.Source, TableName)
    TempDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, TableName)

    DataTable = DataSet.Tables(TableName)

    Return DataTable
End Function
```

To use it, I do :

```
GetDataTable('Table1','SELECT * FROM Table1')
```

This code works perfectly, but when the user doesn't have Select privilege, the line :

```
TempDataAdapter.FillSchema(DataSet, SchemaType.Source, TableName)
```

throws an exception, which is normal, since the code executes a select query as requested.

Though, how to bind a form to a table when the user has only write privilege ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'bound' since you are using weakly-typed datasets here, but anyway - if you are intending to do an insert, then you don't need to pull all the existing rows first using .Fill

Comment: What I mean is to simply have a form to insert data when the user has only insert privileges. Any idea please ?

Comment: There's numerous ways to achieve this. I don't know what other constraints you have around this, so I can't recommend one over the others. However, you could create a strongly-typed dataset and bind that in the designer, then call .update on it. Or you could simply populate a SQL insert query from the textbox etc values. etc etc. But the key point is that you don't ever need to do a SELECT query / .Fill method first.

Comment: a bit strange that the user has insert privs but not select (the other way around I understand)

Comment: I'm designing an application in which a user would be able to insert data based only on his "writing" privilege

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a function that retursn a Ref-Cursor, then the user must have only execute privilege on the function.

Example:

```
create or replace function GetTable(the_table in varchar2) return sys_refcursor is
res sys_refcursor;
begin
open res for 'select * from '||the_table;
return res;
end;
```

Comment: Yes but with this, if the user has 'execute' privilege on that function, he can still see what's in the table without 'select' privilege on it through the cursor, right ? Wouldn't be a inconsistent ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Of course, for this particular sitiation it is a bit useless (or call it "inconsistent"), but it makes sense if you like to exclude certain columns (e.g. column salary in Employee table) or records. Without additional stuff like "Virtual Private Database" a SELECT enables the user to select *everything* from a table. With a function returning a cursor you can easily control it in very deep detail.